# Picasa hangs when trying to import photos

Tags: google-picasa

After I installed Picasa 3.9, I tried to import some photos from a USB stick plugged in. However, it does not show up in Picasa (Ubuntu has no problem recognizing it). There is just a general *Mass Storage Camera* item in the `Import From` field. When I select it, the program hangs. Could it be caused by this [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gvfs/+bug/995886)? Do you know any workaround?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `Import From` field, try to select the "Folder" item and then choose the mounting point where your USB stick is connected by Ubuntu, then you will be able to import your photos.

Comment: It works, thanks a lot! However, it would still be nice if I could select just the attached device from the list.